# Adding WHERE adds 20+ seconds to SQL Azure query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm looking for some advice on speeding up queries in SQL Azure. This is an example of the two queries we're running, when we add a WHERE clause on there, the queries grind to a halt.

Both columns, theTime and orderType are indexed. Can anyone suggest how to make these run faster, or things to do to the query to make it more efficient?

**5.2 seconds:**

```
sum(cast(theTime AS INT)) as totalTime from Orders
```

**20.2 seconds:**

```
 sum(cast(theTime AS INT)) as totalTime from Orders WHERE orderType='something_in_here'
```

---

Here's the relevant information:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
[ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[orderType] nvarchar(90) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[orderTime] nvarchar(90) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_fe2bdbea-c65a-0b85-1de9-87324cc29bff] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID]) 
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [orderTime]
ON [dbo].[Orders] ([orderTime] ASC)
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
ONLINE = OFF)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [actiontime_int]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [orderType]
ON [dbo].[Orders] ([orderType] ASC)
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
ONLINE = OFF)
GO
```

Comment: Just so you know, 20.2s-5.2s is 15s, not 20+s

Comment: Sorry - wrote the question, then re-ran the queries to get exact times to copy/paste :)

Comment: I'm lost - do you want a `COUNT` or do you want the `TOP (1000000)` rows? Not sure I understand why you have both here. A `COUNT` will only return one row.

Comment: Wait.  Count(theTime) is always going to return a single row.  Why add the TOP clause ?

Comment: I know!  I hit "return" and yours popped up.

Comment: Also, is `theTime` nullable? If so, you are probably getting a clustered index scan or an index scan + key lookup. In which case maybe consider adding `theTime` as an `INCLUDE` column to the index on `orderType`. This assumes your query makes any sense at all - are you meaning to discard rows from the count when `theTime` is NULL? If not, just use `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Sorry chaps, was me changing the query because the column names give away who the client is - sum/count was my fault. It's the summation I'm trying to get, the TOP is there to stop it running on 15m rows whist I'm testing it.

Comment: The `TOP` doesn't do what you think it does in this case. It *would* limit the rows if you did something like `SELECT TOP (n) somecol, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.table GROUP BY somecol;` but you're already limiting the result to 1 row with your current query. `TOP` does not make it only count N rows.

Comment: Show your *real* query and just change the column names. The current syntax makes no sense.

Comment: Single column indexes are most of the time pretty much useless. You can drop them both and create one like Aaron suggested - `ON ordertype INCLUDE theTime` .... or `ON ordertype, thetime`

Comment: Post added, real query in there: sum(cast(theTime AS INT)) as totalTime from Orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your query is not doing what you think.  It is taking the first million counts, rather than the count of the first million rows.  I think you want:

```
select sum(cast(theTime AS INT))
from (select top (1000000) Orders
      from Orders
     ) t
```

versus:

```
select sum(cast(theTime AS INT))
from (select top  (1000000) Orders
      from Orders
      WHERE orderType='something_in_here'
     ) t
```

My suspicion is that using the index actually slows things down, depending on the selectivity of the `where` clause.

In the original query, you are reading all the data, sequentially.  This is fast, because the pages just cycle through the processor.

Going through the index slows things down, because the pages are not read in order.  You may be still be reading all the pages (if every page has a matching row), but they are no longer being read in "physical" or "logical" order.  They are being read in the order of the index -- which is likely to be random.

Comment: Solved using a combination of multi column indexes and sub query listed here. Now running the whole thing in 2.8 seconds across all 15m rows! Thanks all.